# href nav links not working after jquery easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar at the site http://deliciousproductions.com.au and the href links in the navbar don't seem to work, the href stuff for #about works but not for actual links like home.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Delicious Productions</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="http://deliciousproductions.com.au">HOME</a></li>              
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://deliciousproductions.com.au/recipes">RECIPES</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>     
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

I feel like it should just be working but maybe this script is interfering because of the onclick?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar
  $(".navbar a").on('click', function(event) {

// Prevent default anchor click behavior
event.preventDefault();

// Store hash
var hash = this.hash;

// Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
// The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes    to scroll to the specified area
 $('html, body').animate({
 scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
}, 1600, 'easeInOutCubic', function(){

  // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
  window.location.hash = hash;
   });
 });
 })
```

cheers, or the prevent default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the `$(".navbar a")` selector selects all your link, and prevents the default behaviour `event.preventDefault();`

Try adding a class `scroll` to the `a` anchor tag and modify your selector to `$(".navbar a.scroll")` selector.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Delicious Productions</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="http://deliciousproductions.com.au">HOME</a></li>              
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://deliciousproductions.com.au/recipes">RECIPES</a></li>   
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>     
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>


$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar
  $(".navbar a.scroll").on('click', function(event) {

    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;

    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
    // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes    to scroll to the specified area
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
     }, 1600, 'easeInOutCubic', function(){

      // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
      window.location.hash = hash;
     });
   });
 })
```

Comment: thank-you worked perfectly :) I can't post again for 90 minutes so would you know how to offset the href scroll so it doesn't put the id'd section right up against the top of the browser, because the navbar is an opaque overlay so it covers whatever px the navbar is when it scrolls down

cheers

Comment: subtract the height of navbar in `scrollTop`. Ex: navbar is 50px height so  `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 50` I just hard coded, you can do `$('.navbar').height()` too..

Comment: thank you Manoj, I used the navbar height method. Amazing that you just know that. Cheers